# Extracting part of string php inside a hidden form input

Tags: php

I accessed a page using php curl that has a form with default values inside hidden inputs, lets say

```
<input type="hidden" name="foo" value="barbazz">
```

How do I get the value `barbazz`, using php, I am thinking of doing this:

```
...
$re = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$i = strpos('foo') + 11;
$val = substr($re, $i, 7);
```

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Use PHP's built in DOM functionality

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($your_html);
```

Read: [DOM library](http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php).

Example:

```
$html = '<html>
    <body>
        <form>
            <input type="hidden" name="foo" value="barbazz">
            <input type="hidden" name="bar" value="something">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);

foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('input') as $input) {
    if ($input->getAttribute('name') == 'foo') {
        echo $input->getAttribute('value');
    }
}
```